# Switch from LBFGS to ADAM optimizer in the middle of training in pytorch

Tags: pytorch

I want to switch the optimizer in the middle of the training
from LBFGS to Adam.
Below is the code that I wrote.

```
optimizer = optim.LBFGS(model.parameters(), lr=0.003)
Use_Adam_optim_FirstTime=True
Use_LBFGS_optim=True

for epoch in range(30000):
    loss_SUM = 0
    for i, (x, t) in enumerate(GridLoader):
        x = x.to(device)
        t = t.to(device)

        if Use_LBFGS_optim:
          def closure():
            optimizer.zero_grad()
            lg, lb, li = problem_formulation(x, t, x_Array,t_Array,bndry,pi)
            loss_total=lg+ lb+ li
            loss_total.backward(retain_graph=True)
            return loss_total
          loss_out=optimizer.step(closure)
          loss_SUM+=loss_out.item()
        
        elif Use_Adam_optim_FirstTime:
          Use_Adam_optim_FirstTime=False
          optimizerAdam = optim.Adam(model.parameters(), lr=0.0003)
          model.load_state_dict(checkpoint['model'])
          optimizerAdam.zero_grad()
          lg, lb, li = problem_formulation(x, t, x_Array,t_Array,bndry,pi)
          lg.backward()
          lb.backward()
          li.backward()
          optimizerAdam.step()
          loss_SUM += lg.item()+lb.item()+li.item()
              
        else:
          optimizerAdam.zero_grad()
          lg, lb, li = problem_formulation(x, t, x_Array,t_Array,bndry,pi)
          lg.backward()
          lb.backward()
          li.backward()
          optimizerAdam.step()
          loss_SUM += lg.item()+lb.item()+li.item()
            
    if loss_SUM<.3 and use_LBFGS_optim == True:
      Use_LBFGS_optim=False
      checkpoint = {'model': model.state_dict(),
                    'optimizer': optimizer.state_dict()}
```

My questions are:

Regarding the closure function:

(1) Is there a way that I can return more than one variable from the closure function?

(2) Is there a way that I can make three backwards in the closure function instead of only one?

(3) Why do I need to set retain_graph to True in loss_total.backward(retain_graph=True) of the closure function

(4) Sometimes, the loss_SUM for the closure function approaches to 1e+29. Is there a way to avoid this problem?

#-----------------------------

Regarding the switch from LBFGS to Adam:

(5) When loss_SUM<0.3 and we go to the "elif" part, the loss reduces however after one epoch,
loss_SUM dramatically increases (e.g., 20 times)

What is the correct way of switching the optimizer from LBFGS to Adam

In general, what are the problems of the above code, and how I can improve it?

Comment: looks like another PINN guy